# getting id passed through a href link in click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a fairly straight forward question. Why can't I use `$('a.view').attr('id')` (Ref //1 in code) in my click function? I tried it and it failed to work but `this.id` works. I guess I primarily want to know the difference in the context of the code below:

**displayRecord.php (The following link calls the click function):**

```
echo '<td><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" id="'.$data['id'].'" class="view" ><input type="button" value="View" /></a></td>';
```

**editTicket.php:**

```
$('a.view').click(
            function(e) 
                {    
                             //1                    
                             var ticket_id = this.id;

                    dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id='+this.id, function(){                           

                    var escalationValue = '';

                    $.post('escalateValue.php',{post_ticket_id:ticket_id}, 
                    function(data) {

                        if (data == 'No'){
                            showCount();
                        }
                    });

                    dlg.dialog('open');

                });

            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('a.view').attr('id')` can match multiple elements, if you have multiple anchors with a `view` class, so you will not necessarily get the clicked element if you use it within a `click` event. `this.id` refers only to the element that was clicked and would also be the fastest way, but to demonstrate you could also do:

```
$(this).attr('id'); // in the click event
```

Answer (score 1):

This this, see if you are getting any alerts or not:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.view', function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    alert(this.id);
});​
```